# two sections on same line

Tags: html, css

I have two sections that are currently on different lines.
They both contain multiple lines of text and I need them to go next to each other.
I need it to have a 10px margin.

Can someone please help me?

Comment: Can you show us a [mcve] of what you’ve got already?

Answer (score 1):

```html
<div style="display: flex">
    <section style="margin-right: 10px; background-color: red;">left section</section>
    <section >left section</section>
</div>
```

you need wrap these sections intro a `display flex` element

Comment: We have runnable code snippets, please use them instead of external links

Comment: Is there any way to do it with a float

Comment: it's possible but very bad pratice, now a days we have flexbox and layout grid, float is useless